# How to add a html element inside a exported const

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have a export const with a big text, and in the middle I want to add a hyperlink element, but this is not working.

My code:

```
const myEmail = '<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>'

export const EXAMPLE = `Example of email: ${myEmail}`
```

Where I import:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { EXAMPLE } from '../../constants/ui.constants'

 const Example: FC<{}> = () => {
   return <div>{EXAMPLE}</div>
 }

 export default Example
```

But this shows like this:

[image]

How can I show the email like this ?
(this was edit through inspect tools)
[image]

Comment: What client are you using to send mail?

Comment: How are you inserting `EXAMPLE` into your template/renderer? Chances are, it's being rendered as plain text instead of HTML.

Comment: @Terry updated the code with where I export it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but you have to be very sure that whatever you are injecting is not something the user has control over, otherwise you will be introducing a XSS vulnerability.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { EXAMPLE } from '../../constants/ui.constants'

const Example: FC<{}> = () => {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={EXAMPLE} />
}

export default Example
```